# Would the desire to be God be considered shirk?

Tags: aqidah

You know how people say 'i wish I could be superman or I wish I had telepathy or teleportation or invincibility powers or I WISH I WAS SUPER SAIYAN GOKU GOD'. Which eventually becomes 'I wish I was God' Is it shirk, if we simply desire the attributes God has for ourselves?

And also what if it transforms into 'I wish I ruled the universe myself as God, I would have created it differently, made it like this, or that, etc.'

I assume that would mean 'I think I know better than God and this way in my opinion is better', which would be shirk?

Or what if it's just 'I wish I was God so I could do whatever the heck I wanted to do, unleash all my desires as I pleased'.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody can become a god, there is only one god, Allah, the Creator the Sustainer the Almighty. Those cartoons are just fiction, made up. Many occult religions use cartoons to spread their religion, they don't preach it except by creating stories about "superheroes".

The Lord is real, but those things that you mentioned are just imagination, so remember that you are human, and your excellence comes from submitting to the Almighty, only he can grant paradise, and the people of paradise can do whatever they want and have whatever they wish. If you submit to him he will make you strong so you don't have to submit to anyone else.

But if you claim that a human is god, or anything else is god, then that is the greatest offence to the Lord who created every single thing from the smallest to the largest, and sustains it and even every new thing that happens he creates it, and it only happens by his permission. So we have to rely on him only.

Humans are a higher life form than any spirit, animal, plant or soil, and yet we are so weak, we can only go a few hours without sleep, water or food. We are so reliant on the Lord who never sleeps or get tired.

Please don't compare anything to Allah, please use a different word at least. Don't listen to the hindu guy.

Answer (score 0):

Wishing to be God means you want to be **equal to Allah** or **replace Allah** and that is Shirk. Fir'own thought himself as God, Allah destroyed him by drowning him in the ocean.

If you want to be a superhuman you can do it in Heaven, but even in heaven many things are unacceptable, like wanting to be a God. Jinns are very fast and powerful like superman and helped Prophet Solomen. You can wish to be like them because they are also just a creation like human. Or better you can actually be like them in Heaven. But wishing to be a God, wishing to be Allah is shirk.

Answer (score -1):

I am not a scholar. **It is just a opinion**

Firstly you should know about shirk's difination : To associate partners with God(Allah)

Wanted to become a God just because it sounds badass is not shirk.(According to me)

Yes it would be shirk if you wanted people to worship **you** as a **self proclaimed so called God**. It is a major sin.

But if you are saying it just to look cool or to feel badass(as an anime character) then it might not be a sin. It is just a joke.

Comment: I think it is shirk, because you associate YOURSELF with Allah, If you want to become a God you are thinking of making yourself equal to Allah, isn't it shirk?

Answer (score -1):

The desire itself is not shirk. Allah gave it to us, and like everything else, it can be used for good and bad. Our actions make us Muslim or Mushrik(polytheist).

Comment: I think it is shirk, because you associate YOURSELF with Allah, If you want to become a God you are thinking of making yourself equal to Allah, isn't it shirk? Just because Allah made us thinkable doesn't mean all our thoughts are acceptable. People who doesn't accept God or worship many Gods have that thought, but it is shirk. Action doesn't make us muslim AT ALL, our thoughts do. Quran 107:4-6 says your action doesn't matter, what matters is you thoughts for doing that.